# Schema Type NewsArticle and articleBody

Tags: schema.org

This is a simple question, about Schemas in JSON-LD .

i.e. Wordpress and the articles contain a fair amount of Ads , and galleries ,etc,  this content will be read by the articleBody.

My question then will be: , Is really necessary to output the gallery info or ads in  articleBody  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`articleBody`](http://schema.org/articleBody) property is for the "actual body of the article".

What is or isn’t part of the article body is the author’s choice, of course. If you think that an advertisement or a gallery is part of your article, include it. Otherwise omit it.

Note that this property expects a `Text` value. If you follow this advice, you can’t include HTML ([it would be interpreted as text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36359288/1591669)), so you can’t have images as part of its value.